# FlexSlider and IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, flexslider

I am building a homepage that includes a calendar carousel coming from an RSS feed. I have placed a FlexSlider inside of the rss reader jquery plugin. It seems to work everywhere, but IE7. Is this a FlexSlider issue? or is it my coding?

See example: http://enews.andover.edu/q/v2/

Many thanks,
Jonathan

Answer (score 4):

In your slider loading code, your HTML or your PHP, the last argument should not contain a comma otherwise it won't work.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I took the last comma out from the Flexslider options JS code and it worked in IE7!